# Characteristic Polymonmial 4x4 Matrix

Tags: polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, jordan-normal-form

I have to find the characteristic polynomial to find Jordan normal form.  I chose to solve this via column expansion on the first determinant, and then row expansion in the inner determinant. But something has clearly went wrong, as I know my answer is incorrect.
Please help me figure this out, I am stuck. Maybe the way I expand the determinant is wrong?

I know my final answer is wrong. 
The correct answer is:

$(x-1)^4$

And here is the question:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Maxima gives $(\lambda-1)(\lambda^3-3\lambda^2-15\lambda+89)$. Are you sure of all the coefficients of $A$?

Comment: That's the solution I have. It might be wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your row expansion, your second term should be

$$-(-3)\det{\begin{pmatrix}
-2& 13\\
-1& (8-\lambda)
\end{pmatrix}}$$

Comment: Thank you. That explains a lot. I have to be carful with these calculations.